# Graphics card upgrade for a "Early 2008" Mac Pro

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards, desktop

I have a "Early 2008" Mac Pro (MacPro3,1) which has a NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT in it (the [mid-range choice](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/faq/mac-pro-default-graphics-cards-dvi-dual-link-mini-displayport.html) at the time).  Unfortunately, it only has 512 MB of VRAM, and that's getting to be more and more of a restriction.  The rest of the computer still meets all my needs (or can be upgraded), so it's time to replace the card.

I am looking for something gaming focused, although I'm not expecting (or looking for) something that can render the latest twitch-based FPS on SuperUltraHigh quality at 120 FPS.  I just want something that can handle the "High" quality settings for moderately recent (e.g. 2014) games at a reasonably smooth speed.  Example games would include Civ V, The Talos Principle, and Wolfenstein: The New Order (with Bootcamp).

That said, I don't know enough about relative performance of cards to know what a good buy for that would be, or even how to define a requirement.  So here's the rest of my requirements:

- Support for the standard Mac boot screens (either natively or via a [flashing service](http://www.macvidcards.com/store/c2/Nvidia_GPUs.html))
- Price under $1000.  If it needs to be flashed, that needs to be included in the price.
- Support for 2+ monitors.  Specific outputs don't matter, although at least one DVI port would be nice. (I'm buying a new monitor at the same time, and can get a adapter as needed for the other.)
- Compatible with the limitations of my computer (PCIe 2.0 x16, 225W max draw)
- Quiet under non-gaming usage (i.e. not significantly louder than the computer's own fans)
- Works under Windows (via Bootcamp) as well.

Nice-to-haves include:

- Price under $500.
- Relatively quiet while gaming (shouldn't be so loud as to be heard in the next room)
- No known compatibility issues with Parallels Desktop

---

I'm currently considering the [GeForce GTX680 Mac Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C81T7ZS), but I don't know if that meets all of my performance or noise requirements.  Any support for buying it or alternative recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: A slight correction: the 8800GT was the high-end gaming option at the time.  The Quadro is a workstation card with poor gaming performance.

Comment: @Mark - Huh. I didn't realize that. That makes a lot of sense, though.  I'm definitely glad I made the choice I did, then, even if it was for the wrong reasons.